# Python/Django: Creating a simpler list from values_list()

Tags: python, django

Consider:

```
>>>jr.operators.values_list('id')
[(1,), (2,), (3,)]
```

How does one simplify further to:

```
['1', '2', '3']
```

The purpose:

```
class ActivityForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ActivityForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.initial['job_record']:
            jr = JobRecord.objects.get(pk=self.initial['job_record'])

            # Operators
            self.fields['operators'].queryset = jr.operators

            # select all operators by default
            self.initial['operators'] = jr.operators.values_list('id') # refined as above.
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Use the `flat=True` construct of the django queryset: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list

From the example in the docs:

```
>>> Entry.objects.values_list('id', flat=True).order_by('id')
[1, 2, 3, ...]
```

Comment: This solution returns a list of integers. To get a list of strings like `['1', '2', '3']` as the OP asked, you need to do `map(str, Entry.objects.values_list('id', flat=True).order_by('id'))`

Comment: this works when you have only one value as per the OP's question. With multiple values, you can use `list(queryset.iterator())`

Comment: can i get multiple values like 
Entry.objects.values_list('id', 'name',flat=True)

but flat=True is working for only single value not for multiple. How to overcome this?

Comment: I was able to make it work only using `list( Entry.objects.values_list('id', flat=True) )`

Answer (score 4):

You need to do ..to get this output ['1', '2', '3']

`map(str, Entry.objects.values_list('id', flat=True).order_by('id'))`

Answer (score 3):

To transform from a flat QuerySet :

```
Entry.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)
```

`<QuerySet [1, 5]>`

to a Python List, you can do this:

```
[*Entry.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)]
```

`[1, 5]`

Comment: in pdb for some reason I couldn't do `list(Entry.objects.values_list('id', flat=True))` so `[*Entry.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)]` works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
    >>> mylist = [(1,), (2,), (3,)]
    >>> [str(x[0]) for x in mylist]
    ['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
x = [(1,), (2,), (3,)]
y = [str(i[0]) for i in x]
['1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: this is a re-implementation of an API available in django that will be much slower than django's generated SQL query