# How to get the Ids from a django model

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-filter

Hi I have two models named A and B. I want to get the ids from my model B and compare it with the id in model A (Foreign Key relation). I used the following method to get the ids 
`a = B.objects.filter(b_id=object.id).values_list('id')`

But a printed a result of `[(82L,), (83L,), (84L,), (85L,)]` instead of `[82, 83 ,]` etc.
How can I get a flat list without the appended `L`s?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python/Django: Creating a simpler list from values\_list()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699462/python-django-creating-a-simpler-list-from-values-list)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`values_list()` by default returns the values grouped into tuples.

If you don't want that, use

```
values_list('id', flat=True)
```

Comment: Yeah, Thanks dhke. But It returned like [82L, 83L, 84L, 85L]. Any idea why?

Comment: @gentle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764713/why-do-integers-in-database-row-tuple-have-an-l-suffix

Comment: @gentle Hard to say without knowing your models and your database. `L` indicates this is a *long integer literal*. Are you using MySQL? MySQL's dbapi implementation seems to [return long integers for all integer types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733002/django-integerfield-returning-long). It should make no difference (other than maybe a little performance-wise).

Comment: the "L" suffixe means "long integer" and is only printed as the _inner representation_ of the `int` object. You don't have to care about it.

Answer (score 2):

These numbers are long integers. As such, they are returned with an `L` suffix. There really is no letter 'L' after the number though. This has been removed in Python 3, since all integers are now treated as long integers. I don't believe what you are seeing is any cause for alarm.

Edit: See [why-do-integers-in-database-row-tuple-have-an-l-suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764713/why-do-integers-in-database-row-tuple-have-an-l-suffix) for more info.

Comment: Hi mfcovington, Thanks but am using python 2.7. That's why the concern

Comment: @gentle Ya, I figured you must be using python 2, since you are seeing it. Is it actually causing problems or just bothering you? If you want to display it for some reason and not have the `L` included, you can use `str()` which should return just the digits.

Comment: Because later I need to compare these ids with real int ids from other models. That's why this concern

Comment: @gentle: But they are real integers, a 'long' integer can just be larger than a 'plain' integers. You can compare them just fine to one another. See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks a lot mfcovington :)

Comment: No problem! By the way, try this: `x = long(5); y = 5; type(x); type(y); x == y`