# How do i convert the just the values from a result set from of a django query into a list?

Tags: python, django, django-views

When i execute the following query to get a query set result

```
peak_power_machine = MachinetoDatatype_Mapping.objects.filter(datatype__in=1]).values('machine_id') 
print(peak_power_machine)
```

I get the following result when i tried it.

```
<QuerySet [{'machine_id': 1}, {'machine_id': 3}]>
```

But what i need is a simple list like [1,3...] with just the machine ids in it.

How do i do that? Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python/Django: Creating a simpler list from values\_list()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699462/python-django-creating-a-simpler-list-from-values-list)

Comment: Will you later *fetch* the `Machine`s with that `id`, since then another query can do these two queries in once.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem no i just need it to do some calculations

Answer (score 2):

Use `values_list`

**Ex:**

```
peak_power_machine = MachinetoDatatype_Mapping.objects.filter(datatype__in=1]).values_list('machine_id', flat=True) 
print(peak_power_machine)
```

**[MoreInfo](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)**

Comment: Cool. Now i get <QuerySet [1, 3]> :) . But is there anyway to just get [1, 3] from that. I'm new to django

Comment: @user6714507: yes, by passing it through the `list(..)` function. A queryset is an iterable over its elements.